# parser amp-selector value to php

Tags: php, amp-html

How can I get the value of the amp selector and save it in a php variable

```
  <amp-selector multiple layout="container" class="radio-selector"
        on="select: AMP.setState({ 
          selectedOption: event.targetOption,
          allSelectedOptions: event.selectedOptions 
        })">

      <div option="1">1</div>
      <div option="1">1</div>
      <div option="1">1</div>

    </amp-selector>
     <input type="text" name="" [value]="allSelectedOptions.join(' ')">
    <?php 
       $category_id ='"selectedOption"';
      // $category_id ='{{selectedOption}}';
         // $category_id=remove_special_characters($category_id);
         $int = (int) filter_var($category_id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
          echo $int; 
          $filter= get_filter_category($category_id);

    ?>
```

I tried multiple ways like domdocument but nothing seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
//$num = "";
$optionTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
print_r($optionTags);
for ($i = 0; $i < $optionTags->length; $i++ ) {
  if ($optionTags->item($i)->hasAttribute('selected') 
         ) {
       $num = $optionTags->item($i)->nodeValue;
  }
}
echo "Num is " . $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would need this for a form.
Hence you will have a submit button or something similar.
Way to go here is to link your submit button to another file that reads the selection (possible via POST) and redirects you to the desired page.

If you just want to save your selection without doing anything, you could use amp-bind and a JSON Endpoint. The Endpoint gets called when changed, with the selection as parameter and saves it instead of delivering any files what so ever.